# Android: Different widget layouts for Honeycomb/Gingerbread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm working a personal project that's going to include a home-screen widget updated with information from a service - I'm developing using a Android 3.1 tablet (physical) as well as an Android 2.3 emulated phone.

For the Honeycomb version, I'd like to use the StackView, building up 3-4 pages which the user can swipe through, whereas this isn't supported on pre-Honeycomb devices, so is there an easy way to

- have Honeycomb devices use a StackView but have Gingerbread/earlier use a TextView (I think this can be done by using res/layouts-v1{1,2,3,4}
- Have the RemoteView detect which it is and clear/create the StackView items or set the text on the TextView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate different layout for pre and post Honeycomb by using the v11 qualifier in your layout names. You can also use the Build class to detect what [Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) version you're running on and then load the appropriate layout.

Comment: @kgfullerton you should accept this answer as correct if it helped you (it should have, this is a good solution).